# extract of text from column and copy it into a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to extract text from a column and place it into a column of its own.

The Text is always 16 characters long in a DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM format, appears  the text "On-site" which only ever appears once in the text and is always followed by the text "Off-Site" which also only appears once.

This is the code that I am using at the moment but I dont have it set right at all.

```
WITH
   LEFT(SUBSTRING(eventcomments,
                     CHARINDEX('On-Site', r.eventcomments) + 1, 16),
                     CHARINDEX('Off-Site', r.eventcomments) - 1) AS Onsite
```

I am getting this error message.

```
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected result?

Comment: I am not sure how to lay it out here, the column that has the text is very large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that I would have to extract from a string column first occurrence of a date/time values having following format `DD/MM/YYYY HH:SS` (length = 16 chars) then I would use `PATINDEX` instead of `CHARINDEX` thus:

```
SELECT  *, 
    SUBSTRING(
        x.StringColumn, 
        NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-1][0-9]/[0-3][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][ ][0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]%', x.StringColumn), 0), 
        16) AS DateTimeExtracted
FROM    (VALUES 
    ('Bogdanel 01/02/2017 03:04 hei ho'),
    ('Georgel 05/06/2017 07:08 danga langa'),
    ('Suna''n asfintit 09/11/2018 11:22 hei talanga'),
    ('Danga langa. Pai da.'),
    ('   '),
    (NULL)
) x(StringColumn)
```

Results:

```
StringColumn                                 DateTimeExtracted
-------------------------------------------- -----------------
Bogdanel 01/02/2017 03:04 hei ho             01/02/2017 03:04
Georgel 05/06/2017 07:08 danga langa         05/06/2017 07:08
Suna'n asfintit 09/11/2018 11:22 hei talanga 09/11/2018 11:22
Danga langa. Pai da.                         NULL
                                             NULL
NULL                                         NULL
```

Comment: thank you, this will work for me. Can I duplicate it if I need to find the second occurrence of date/time values (under a new column)

Comment: @Michael: It's possible but there is no mention within question about second/third occurrence. You should update current question by adding this requirement and also by adding some examples of source strings.

Comment: you are right, apologies I got over excited! You have done everything that I asked for perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the values are not in the field.  A simple method just adds them in for the `charindex()`:

```
  LEFT(SUBSTRING(eventcomments,
                 CHARINDEX('On-Site', r.eventcomments + 'On-Site') + 1, 16),
       CHARINDEX('Off-Site', r.eventcomments + 'Off-Site') - 1
      ) AS Onsite
```

You'll need to test the code to see if it does what you want.  This approach will prevent the error.