# Changing the format of an AS column from text to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, ssms, charindex

I am using this code to pull out a date and time from a text field.

```
    SELECT
    LEFT(SUBSTRING(eventcomments,
    CHARINDEX('Off-Site:', eventcomments) + 9, 17),
    CHARINDEX('Off-Site:', eventcomments)) AS Departed
```

which creates a Departed column  dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm

I wanted to convert this from text to a datetime format so I added the following code.

```
    SELECT
    CONVERT(datetime,LEFT(SUBSTRING(eventcomments,
    CHARINDEX('Off-Site:', eventcomments) + 9, 17),
    CHARINDEX('Off-Site:', eventcomments))) AS Departed
```

but I got the following error message,

```
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

My question is,

How can I change the format of the Departed column from text to a datetime format.

Comment: To extract date/time value as string from original text I would use solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885387/extract-of-text-from-column-and-copy-it-into-a-new-column and then I would use `CONVERT(DATETIME, DateTimeExtracted, 103)` to convert extracted d/t value from string to `DATETIME`.

Comment: Extracting dates and times from strings can be a tricky business.  If at all possible it is recommended you avoid this by storing dates and times in their own data types.  You need to find the row(s) that are raising this error.  The most likely cause is they are not formatted consistently.

Comment: @Bogdan Sahlean Hey mate, because I need to get two dates from the text  I cant use PATINDEX so I have opted to work with CHARINDEX as I can use that multiple times.

Comment: Then this question should specify that source string have two (or more ?) date/time values, and those values should be extracted from original text and then converted to proper data type? Last time I asked you to add also some sample date. Could you please update this question with this info?

Comment: I dont want someone to write all the code for me, I want an idea of how to do it so that I can take it away and work on it myself. If I get one example then I can tweak it for the rest of my query and I am learning. I have written my question in order to give me enough information to be able to do that.  Thank you for your time, I have used your previous answer to grow and move forwards I greatly appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the CAST function:

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(SUBSTRING(eventcomments,
            CHARINDEX('Off-Site:', eventcomments) + 9, 17),
            CHARINDEX('Off-Site:', eventcomments)) 
          AS DATETIME) AS Departed
```

Like `SELECT CAST('05/10/1983 19:00' as datetime)`

Comment: My date data was corrupt so I separated date and time into their own columns and ran with just a `time` conversion (as @destination-data suggested) which was the key piece of information. If the data was not corrupted on my table then this would have worked perfectly. Thank you.